# Unable to get local issuer certificate after adding swagger to the api c#

Tags: c#, iis, swagger

Before adding the swagger the api works fine in all the environments but after adding swagger it is working only in local and throwing error message "Unable to get local issuer certificate" in dev environment[image: reference image]

Comment: Similar questions you can use as a reference: [https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/538](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/538).